# Convex set: 2D representation of $\|\textbf{x} - \Pi \textbf{x}\| = \min_{\textbf{y} \in \textbf{C}}\|\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}\|$

Tags: metric-spaces, convex-geometry

Metric projection (MP) and separation theorems

Let $\textbf{C}$ be a closed convex subset of a Hilbert space $\textbf{V}$.

For any $\textbf{x} \in \textbf{V}$, there exists a unique $\Pi \textbf{x} \in \textbf{C}$ such that
$$
\|\textbf{x} - \Pi \textbf{x}\| = \min_{\textbf{y} \in \textbf{C} \quad(1)}\|\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}\| \quad (2)
$$

**Here are my questions**:

- Does this 2D drawing corresponds to the statement
- If yes can we say in that case that this implies that $ \Pi \textbf{x} = \textbf{y}$? (3)

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what they mean in the theorem. What do you mean by 'y' ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Jakobian. I'm not sure to understand to which "y" you are referring to. I made another drawing and numbered all the "y"

Comment: The 'y' in $(2)$ isn't fixed, so I don't understand what 'y' do you mean

Comment: @Jakobian. No it isn't fixed, it can theoretically be any point in $\textbf{C}$, but because of the equality, there is only one point where it can be true: only where $\Pi\textbf{x}$ is equal to $\textbf{y}$. right?

Comment: For example you have $\int_0^1 dy$, right. That's what I mean by $y$ isn't fixed. There's no one $y$ to which we can refer to.

Comment: All we can say is, that $\Pi x$ is a minimal point of a function on $C$, $y\mapsto ||x-y||$

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks a lot @Jakobian